# Apex Trigger After Insert on Lead

Tags: apex, trigger

I am trying to create an Apex Trigger on Lead. After the lead has been inserted,if it has a 'Company' field attached to it, it should match the Company field with an existing Account Name. If a Account Name has been found then the Lead.Account__c field should be set to the found Account.id.

The problem: When performing a bulk insert on lead with a pre-populated Company fields, the Account__c field is not being updated properly( after the insert event has finished, the Account__c field should be set to the Account.id where Account.Name == Lead.Company ).

Example I am trying to insert 100 leads: 99 of those having the Company field set to 'Account1' and 1 having the Company field set to 'Account2'. ( Account1, Account2 already exist in our salesforce instance). 
The Expected Results should be 99 of the leads have their Account__c field set to the Account1.id  and 1 Lead has the Account__c field set to Account2.id. 
The actual Results 1 lead has the Account__c field set to Account1.id and 1 Lead has the Account__c field set to Account2.id.

Here is the method from the Lead Handler Class which is not working properly:

```
  public void LinkLeadToAccount() { 

        Map<String,List<id>  > Accounts = new Map< String,List<id> >(); 
        Map <id,List<id>> accMap = new Map< id,List<id>>();
        List<Lead> leads = new List<Lead>();
        List<Lead> leads_to_update = new List<Lead>();
        List<id> leadIds= new List<id>();

        for (Lead l: newLeads.values()){
            if(l.Company!=null)
                {
                if (!Accounts.containsKey(l.Company))  {
                   Accounts.put(l.company,new  List <Id> {l.id }); 
                }
                else{
                   Accounts.get(l.Company).add(l.id);    
                } 

               leads.add(l);
            } 
    }



 Set<String> setName = new Set<String>();      
 List<Account> accts =  [select Name,id from Account where Name in :Accounts.keySet()];  
    for(Account a:  accts){ 
      if(!setName.contains(a.name))
      { setName.add(a.name);
        accMap.put(a.id,accounts.get(a.Name) );   
      }
    }


    for( ID actID : accMap.keySet() ) {
        Lead newLead = new Lead();

            System.debug('List<account> ' + actID);
    for( ID leadID : accMap.get( actId ) ) {

            newLead.id =  leadID;
            newLead.Account__c = actId;
            leads_to_update.add(newLead);
            break;         
    }

    }        
        update leads_to_update;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using less intermediate maps and lists as each extra one makes the code harder to follow. Also naming them more explicitly can help too. I think this (haven't tested it) is what you are looking to do:

```
public void LinkLeadToAccount() {

    Set<String> companies = new Set<String>();
    for (Lead l: newLeads.values()) {
        if (l.Company != null) companies.add(l.Company);
    }

    if (companies.size() > 0) {

        // Pick most recent Account where more than one with same name
        Map<String, Id> accountNameToId = new Map<String, Id>();
        for (Account a : [
                select Name, Id
                from Account
                where Name in :companies
                order by CreatedDate
                ]) {
            accountNameToId.put(a.Name, a.Id);
        }

        if (accountNameToId.size() > 0) {
            Lead[] updates = new Lead[] {};
            for (Lead l: newLeads.values()) {
                if (l.Company != null) {
                    Id accountId = accountNameToId.get(l.Company);
                    if (accountId != null) {
                        updates.add(new Lead(Id = l.Id, Account__c = accountId));
                    }
                }
            }
            update updates;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I will try this implementation and will see if it solves my problem.